# Android Fragment で onCreateView が呼ばれずに onDestroy が呼ばれることはありますか

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

自作のアプリを実機へインストールしています。
端末の電源ボタンを押し休止モードから復帰したところ、例外が発生し落ちたのでこの問題を修正したいのですが、原因がわかりません。

以下のようなコードで、 `onDestroy` 中の `myfield` が `null` であるという例外が発生していました。
(crashlyticsが拾ったスタックトレースを最後に添付しています。)

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyClass myfield;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        myfield = new MyClass();
...
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        myfield.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myfield.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

`myfield`への代入はこの1箇所のみであり、`onCreateView`が実行されたのであれば`null`になることはないはずだと考えております。
また、コードを変更し`onCreateView`内で例外が発生するようにしてみたところ、`onDestroy`は呼ばれないことも確認しました。
(追記)加えて、`onDestroyView`内でも`myfield`のメソッドを呼ぶ実装をしておりますが、ここでは例外が発生していません(そもそも呼ばれていない？)。

休止から復帰したタイミング、というところになにか通常には無いフローがあるような気もするのですが、 `onCreateView` が呼ばれずに `onDestroy` が呼ばれるような条件はあるのでしょうか。
また、ありえる場合、どのような記述で対応するのが一般的なのでしょうか。

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {my.app/my.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void my.app.MyClass.onDestroy()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3706)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void my.app.MyClass.onDestroy()' on a null object reference
       at my.app.MyFragment.onDestroy(MyFragment.java:83)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2006)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1076)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1954)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:313)
       at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onDestroy(ActionBarActivity.java:169)
       at my.app.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:97)
       at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6169)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3693)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: このFragmentは、FragmentTransactionではどのように扱っていますか？（addで指定したIDに割り当て / ただaddするのみ　など）

Comment: @fkm [こちらのサイト](http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-tips-31-fragment-pager-adapter/)を参考にして、Fragmentは[FragmentPagerAdapter内で生成](https://github.com/suwa-yuki/TraditionalColorViewer/blob/master/TraditionalColorViewer/src/jp/classmethod/android/sample/fragmentpager/TraditionalColorPagerAdapter.java#L42)しています。
ご質問への返答としては、FragmentTransactionは使用していません…ということになるでしょうか。
(FragmentTransactionというものを意識したことがなかったので、頓珍漢な回答でしたら申し訳ありません)

Comment: なるほどです。再現するか手元で試してみますね

Comment: 再現したので回答としてつけました。勉強になりました

Answer (score 5, accepted):

再現しました。

### 前提

`FragmentPagerAdapter`は次のように、インデックスを伝えて各ページを生成してるとします。

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return ItemFragment.newInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

この状態で、１ページだけスワイプで切り替えた状態で、ホームボタンで中断します。当然ですがActivityは保持しない設定にしておきます。

LogCatを貼って挙動を説明します。

```
07-28 22:22:24.977    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=0
07-28 22:22:24.977    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=1
07-28 22:22:24.978    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=2
07-28 22:22:24.978    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=3
07-28 22:22:31.172    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onCreateView index=1
07-28 22:22:31.173    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onCreateView index=2
07-28 22:22:31.174    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onCreateView index=3
07-28 22:22:35.162    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=0
07-28 22:22:35.162    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=1
07-28 22:22:35.162    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=2
07-28 22:22:35.163    8859-8859/com.mokelab.pager V/Item﹕ onDestroy index=3
```

まず、一度でも`attach`された`Fragment`の`onDestroy()`が呼ばれているのがわかります。なので、`index=0`も`onDestroy()`が呼ばれています。

そしてアプリスイッチで再開すると、`index=0`の`Fragment`の`View`は生成する必要のない位置にいるので、1〜3の`onCreateView()`が呼ばれていますね。

そしてこの状態で再度ホームボタンで中断すると、やはり`index=0`の`Fragment`は復元されているので、`onDestroy()`が呼ばれています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。当方でも同様のコードを書いて再現するのを確認しました。加えて、`onCreateView()`が呼ばれなかった`Fragment`(上記の例では`index=0`のもの)ではやはり`onDestroyView()`が呼ばれないことも確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment`は必ずUIを持つ要素ではありません。`Activity`のView階層と紐付かない`Fragment`を作ることもでき、この場合は`onCreateView()`は呼ばれません。

以下、公式ドキュメントの、[Adding a fragment without a UI](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)の内容です。

> To add a fragment without a UI, add the fragment from the activity using add(Fragment, String) (supplying a unique string "tag" for the fragment, rather than a view ID). This adds the fragment, but, because it's not associated with a view in the activity layout, **it does not receive a call to onCreateView()**. So you don't need to implement that method.

`onCreateView()`で保持したフィールドは、対応する`onDestroyView()`で解放するのがベターかと思います<s>が、`onDestroyView()`も呼び出されないとのことですので、`Activity`と`Fragment`を紐付けるロジックに問題があるように思います。</s>

- `add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`
- `replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`

を使わず、

- `add (Fragment fragment, String tag)`

を用いつつ、`getView()`で取得した`View`を自前で`addSubview()`していないでしょうか。

**UPDATE:** @fkmさんの回答より、`FragmentPagerAdapter`のcache実装に由来する不都合と思われるので、後半を取り消します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。該当記述箇所は今回UIを使用しているので無関係かと思い読み飛ばしていました。
一旦ライフサイクルが始まると必ず[ライフサイクル図](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)の通りのフローをたどるのだと思い込んでいましたが、そうではないのですね。
今回は、(`onCreate`は呼んだから)`onDestroy`を呼んだ、ただし`onCreateView`は呼ばなかったので`onDestroyView`も呼んでいない、という挙動だったのでしょうね。
どういう条件でそうなるのかは不明ですが、これなら確かに納得がいきます。
そもそも、`onCreate(View)`で生成したものの後始末は`onDestroy(View)`で行うべき、というのは全くその通りだと思いますのでそのように対処します。